# Input data not changing. Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using laravel and ajax request. After call back I pulling updated info into my input form

```html
<a data-post-table-id="1" data-post-id="55" id="greenButtonForm1" data-post-color="#80c87d" data-post-title="6346" href="javascript:PopUpShowEdit(1)">
   <i class="fas fa-adjust" style="color:green;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```

But when I am writing in console in browser:

```
$("#greenButtonForm1").data();
```

I'm getting this my previous data before updated page

```
postTitle: 6346
postColor: "#ff464a"
postId: 55
postTableId: 1
__proto__: Object
```

I have no idea why jQuery doesn't want to fetch the correct info:

```js
function PopUpShowEdit(x) {
   $("#popup").css('display',"block");
   var total;
   total = $("#greenButtonForm"+x).data();
   $("#color").val(total.postColor);
   console.log(total);
   $("#break_post_id").val(total.postId);
   $("#id_of_post_table").val(total.postTableId);
   $("#description").val(total.postTitle);
   console.log(total.postColor);
}
```

This is the end of ajax request

```js
success:function(response) {
   console.log(response);
   $("#redButBreak"+ post_id).css('display',"none");
   $("#greenButBreak"+ post_id).css('display',"block");
   console.log("CREATING" + post_id);
   const listItem = document.querySelector("#greenButBreak"+post_id);
   const newItem = document.createElement('td');
   newItem.innerHTML = '<a data-post-id="'+response[0]+'"  id="greenButtonForm'+response[3]+'" data-post-color="'+response[2]+'" data-post-title="'+response[1]+'" href="javascript:PopUpShowEdit('+response[3]+')"><i class="fas fa-adjust" style="color:green;"></i></a> ';
   listItem.parentNode.replaceChild(newItem, listItem);
}
```

Comment: It looks like my js fucntion can't see that my input is changed ... idk

Comment: Have you duplicated the same id and are reading data from the original one ? ID's must be unique by definition. What does `console.log($('[id="greenButtonForm1"]').length)` show you?

Comment: I can't understand. All my data is correctly taking from db. Input form is correct. But data function works wierd. If I will write $("#greenButtonForm1").attr("data-post-color"); . It will take all correctly

Comment: Show us more of the relevant code. Multiple possible reasons this could be happening but without seeing more code all we can do is guess

Comment: var colorOfForm = $("#greenButtonForm1").attr("data-post-color");
        var tableidofForm = $("#greenButtonForm1").attr("data-post-table-id");
        var postidofForm = $("#greenButtonForm1").attr("data-post-id");
        var descriptionofForm = $("#greenButtonForm1").attr("data-post-title"); I made it like this and it works. idk

Comment: function PopUpShowEdit(x){
        $("#popup").css('display',"block");
        var total;
        total = $("#greenButtonForm"+x).data();
        $("#color").val(total.postColor);console.log(total);
        $("#break_post_id").val(total.postId);
        $("#id_of_post_table").val(total.postTableId);
        $("#description").val(total.postTitle);
        console.log(total.postColor);
    } I mean my code is big.. this data doesn't work. Idk

Comment: Please [edit] the question with that code formatted. Very hard to read big code blobs in comments and makes it much harder for future readers to see the problem

Comment: okay nvm my variabels for only for one time, next it will not work... Why ?@@@!!!$!@$!

Comment: My guess is you are getting the data before ajax completes and are getting it from original element not new one

Comment: I will add one more part of ajax. Mb here is problem idk

Comment: I'm changing element. And I tryed $("#greenButtonForm1").data(); in browser . And it also didn't work. After 10 second for sure ajax made call back

Comment: You never answered if same id already exists. Where do you call `PopUpShowEdit()`?

Comment: showing only length 1 console.log($('[id="greenButtonForm1"]').length) = 1

Comment: Sounds like some other plugin or function changes the data. The attribute can have one value and the stored object set with data() another